# Using arithmetic expressions with null

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I've written an sql statement which selects columns from a specific table.
However, the issue I am experiencing, is being able to show the data in middle name column, i don't want that happening.

I'm not quite sure where to add the null keyword, as any combination results in a multitude of error messages.

Trying to put null and arithmetic operations using select.

The statement I am using is:

```
SELECT First_Name, Surname, Middle_Name as null,
 Price_Per_Unit, Vat, Quantity, Discount, Total_Cost,
 (Price_Per_Unit * Quantity) + Vat + Discount AS Total_Cost FROM Invoices
```

Help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  Your title talks about "arithmetic expressions" but it doesn't make sense to do arithmetic on a middle name column.  Do you want your query to return a middle name column that is always `NULL`?  Are you trying to remove the middle name column from the results entirely?  Something else?

Comment: Trying to remove the middle name column from the results entirely by using null in the select statement.

Comment: That's self-contradictory.  If you remove the middle name column from the results entirely, there is by definition no column so there is no place that you could return a `NULL`.

Comment: sorry, not the column, but the data that's in the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of selecting Middle_Name from the table, just put NULL into that column (assuming you need to have a middle name column in the output and you just to enforce that it's always null).

```
SELECT INV.First_Name, INV.Surname, NULL AS MiddleName,
 INV.Price_Per_Unit, INV.Vat, INV.Quantity,    INV.Discount, INV.Total_Cost,
 (INV.Price_Per_Unit * INV.Quantity) + INV.Vat + INV.Discount AS Total_Cost FROM Invoices INV
```

Comment: Answered my question effectively! Brilliant!